# What exactly Apache Tomcat do?

Tags: tomcat

I am not really into this servlet programming kind of programming, I actually want to be a game developer but as part of my course I had to study servlets and apache tomcat is related to them. I wanted to know what exactly tomcat is for? What I know about apache is:
- It is used to make our computer a server.
- We deploy our servlets on the server which we made through apache.
This might be wrong because I have not studied the tomcat that much. So I was thinking that if tomcat makes our computer an server can anyone else who is on his/her own computer can access thing on our server? if not then why do we use tomcat and why do we even deploy the servlets on them(or should I say why do we even develop servlets) this is my question and this might be dumb thanks for you response.
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score -1):

Tomcat is a java web server, which handles client connection negotiation, security, routing, caching, and all the basic functions of a web server.  Servlets are mini applications designed to run on the web, which are run on the server, which when routed does whatever its purpose is and returns the output to the server, which then is sent to the client.  If an error occurs the server should handle it gracefully and show an error page as opposed to failing outright.

Here is some more info on servers: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Server_(computing)